# Time.DeltaTime suddenly stops working in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've been making a 2D shooter game in unity and I run my game on a global timer using the code
timer += Time.deltaTime
this usually just gives me a timer that works like a stop watch however suddenly the value of my timer variable just fluctuates at around 0.0003-0.0001 when running the script when it should be going 1 2 3 4 5 etc for every second. It has done it before and without me changing anything to my knowledge it just fixed itself after 30ish mins but now it's happened again. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: is it in `Update()` or `Start()`

Comment: It would help if you show the code.

Comment: It was in the Update(). I deleted it and put it back and now it worked again smh. I isolated it in it's own script and it didn't work then. But just deleting it and putting it back has somehow fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```
float time = 0f;
float timer = 5f;

void Update()
{
    time += Time.deltaTime;
    if(time >= timer)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

The code is adding 1f to `time` every second. Using `Time.deltaTime` makes it so that it will be the same at any framerate (for example if the framerate is 30fps, it won't add a second 30 times in one second ) and if `time` (the amount of seconds) surpasses timer, we run what is in between the if statement.